# Склонение мужских фамилий, например Биц

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Как правильно написать фамилию Биц (муж. рода) в родительном падеже?

Answer (score 3):

Все  мужские фамилии, имеющие основы на согласные и нулевое окончание в именительном падеже (на письме они кончаются согласной буквой, ь или й), кроме фамилий на -ых, -их, склоняются как существительные второго склонения мужского рода.
Правильно: Бица.

**Обновление**

Подробнее [здесь](http://gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_8_familii/).